# Union of Nested Schemas in Marshmallow

Tags: python, polymorphism, marshmallow

would like to be able to do this:

```
class Foo(Schema):
    attr1 = fds.Str(required=True)
    attr2 = fds.Int(required=True)

class Bar(Schema):
    attr3 = fds.Bool(required=True)
    attr4 = fds.Float(required=True)

class Test(Schema):
    attr5 = Union[Nested(Foo), Nested(Bar)]
```

Basically i need to load a dict into Test that has an attribute (attr5) ta can hold two different nested schemas. I found implementations of `Union` but they only work for types and not schemas. I wanted to know if this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you do `class Test(Foo,Bar):`?

Comment: Unfortunately no because i will inherit all the attributes but they wont be under `atttr5`

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is called polymorphism (what you expect in attr5 can be of either Foo or Bar type).

There is no such feature in marshmallow. You may use [marshmallow-oneofschema](https://pypi.org/project/marshmallow-oneofschema/) for this.

```py
class MyUberSchema(OneOfSchema):
    type_schemas = {"foo": Foo, "bar": Bar}


class Test(Schema):
    attr5 = List(Nested(MyUberSchema))
```